# Button in table view not responding with its cell number

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitableview

I have one table view in each cell two button as edit and cancel. when i click on edit button at same time in same cell number, cancel button image should chacnge. for example. When user select seond cells edit button only cancel button in second cell should change its image.

my problem is when i clicking on any cells edit button another cells cancel button image is changing automatically.

i want that  when user clicks on first cell only first cell cancel button should changed not others cell? pls give me sample how we can do this? As i know this haapning coz of reuse the cell?

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     simpleTableIdentifier = @"MenuNameCell";
     MenuNameCell *cell = (MenuNameCell *)[tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

      if (cell== nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuNameCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"---------new cell agin");   
    }
       else
    {
        NSArray *arrayView = [cell.contentView subviews];
        for (UIView *vTemp in arrayView)
        {
            [vTemp removeFromSuperview];
        }

        NSLog(@"---No New Cell hiiii");

    }
    // Creating Label Menu Name
    _nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 11, 82, 21)];
    _nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _nameLabel.text =  [_hotel._orderedMenus objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Creating Label Menu Cost
    _amountMenu   = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(167, 13, 44, 21)];
    _amountMenu.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _amountMenu.text  = [[_hotel._menuPrices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];

    // Creating Text Field For Order Quantity
    _textFieldQuantity = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125,14,42,21)];
    _textFieldQuantity.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    _textFieldQuantity.text = [[_hotel._selectedQuantity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];

    // Creating Button For Check Order
    _checkButton  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_checkButton setFrame:CGRectMake(232, 13, 25, 28)];
    [_checkButton setTag:indexPath.row];
    [_checkButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editQuantity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    // Creating Button For CANCEL Order
    _cancelButton  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(265, 13, 25, 28)];
    [_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_cancelButton setTag:indexPath.row];
    [_cancelButton addTarget:self  action:@selector(cancelOreder:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [imageViewArray addObject:_checkButton];
    [imageViewArray addObject:_cancelButton];


    // Adding All To Content View
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_nameLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_amountMenu];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_textFieldQuantity];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_checkButton];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_cancelButton];


    //objc_setAssociatedObject(_checkButton, iindex, indexPath,OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN );

    return cell;
    }


      -(void)editQuantity:(id)sender{


    button = (UIButton *)sender;
    row = button.tag;
    col = button.titleLabel.tag;
    _textFieldQuantity.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_over.png"];
    [_checkButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *buttonImageCancel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
    [_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageCancel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _cancelButton.tag =  0;

}


     -(void)cancelOreder:(id)sender{


    button = (UIButton *)sender;
    row = button.tag;
    NSLog(@"The Row Selected iS At Cancel Order ISSSS----%d", row);
    if (_cancelButton.tag ==  0){
        _textFieldQuantity.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        UIImage *buttonImageCancel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_over.png"];
        [_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageCancel  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        UIImage *buttonImageCancel1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.png"];
        [_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageCancel1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"];
        [_checkButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _cancelButton.tag = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert =  [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"iHomeDelivery" message:@"Do You Want To Cancel the Order" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

}

     -(void)removeEntry:(id) sender{
    _hotel = [HotelList sharedInstance];
    NSLog(@"Called...%d",[_hotel._orderedMenus count]);
    NSLog(@"Button index is ------%d", row);
    if ([_hotel._orderedMenus count] > 1) { // if table contains multiple menus
        [_hotel._orderedMenus removeObjectAtIndex:row];
        [_hotel._menuPrices removeObjectAtIndex:row];
        [_hotel._selectedQuantity removeObjectAtIndex:row];
        NSNumber *aNumber;
        int sum = 0;
        for (aNumber in _hotel._menuPrices)
        {
            int aInt = [aNumber intValue];
            sum = sum + aInt;
        }
        _labelFinalBillAmount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum];
    }
    else if ([_hotel._orderedMenus count] ==  1){ // if table contain only single menu // Here All array gets Empty
        [_hotel._orderedMenus removeAllObjects];
        _labelFinalBillAmount.text = @"0";
    }
    NSLog(@"--count is %d",[_hotel._orderedMenus count]);
    [_tableviewMenus reloadData];
}
```

Comment: [Have a look at this post](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/) to make `UITableViewCell` custom, it'll solve your many problems, including re-using cells, changing background etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are using custom cell right then right this code in to your custom class and get the particular sender of particular cell

```
-(IBAction)yourButtonMehod:(id)sender
{
    UIView *senderButton = (UIView*) sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [(UITableView *)self.superView indexPathForCell: (UITableViewCell*)[[senderButton superView]superView]];
}
```

Now, you can get the sender and using indexpath.row you can do anything

Answer (score 0):

In your button action method

```
-(IBAction)cellButtonPressed:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch * touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: bulletinTable];
    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [bulletinTable indexPathForRowAtPoint: location];
}
```

And your cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
[cell.accessory addTarget:self action:@selector(cellButtonPressed:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This should work.

Comment: how could i change button image with its IndexPath position button

Comment: I dont understand ur problem that you mentioned in comment ?please give details

Comment: i want to change cancel button image if user click on edit button on same cell. For Ex; If user click on third cell edit button then at same time third cell cance l button get chacged but its not happning